# I encountered a problem is that I can not use apt to install software normally on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management

When I use apt or apt-get to install a software , the terminal showed me a error.Can anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by apt)
apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full input and output of what you did. This snippet is too terse.

Comment: That sounds as if some core system libraries cannot be accessed on your system. Tell us what happened. You had an improper system shutdown? Tried something on the terminal?

Comment: @vanadium This is a ubuntu server runs on laboratory，shared for some people to use this server.I also dont know what happened on this server some time ago,but when i tried to executed apt command ,termianl showed me above errors.

Comment: On my 18.04.5 LTS system, the version of libapt-pkg is `libapt-pkg.so.5.0` not `libapt-pkg.so.6.0` so I suspect it is either the version of `apt` or possibly the version of the underlying python system that is messed up. I've seen something like this where the user has installed an unsupported version of `apt` elsewhere - what does `type -a apt` say?

Comment: @steeldriver `type -a apt` shows `apt is /usr/bin/apt`,whether I should change `libapt-pkg.so.6.0` to `libapt-pkg.so.5.0`? Or other something to do to resolve it.

Comment: @steeldriver It is possible to reinstall `apt` on ubuntu system?